# Add output from Reducer to a List in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to add the output from the `reducer` into a `list` and then access and then print the list after all the values have been read.

Here is what I am doing:-

```
public class Reducer extends Reducer<Text, BooleanWritable, Text, BooleanWritable> {
  public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Reducer.class);
  public List<String> keys= new ArrayList<>(1000);

  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<BooleanWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    for (BooleanWritable value : values) {
        keys.add(key.toString());
      context.write(key, value);
    }
    print(keys);
  }

  private void print(String keys) {
    for (String key : keys) {
      LOG.info(key);  
  }
}
```

But, it is not working as expected. 
I want to print the list only once after all the values from the reducer are added to the `list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use which is called once per reducer task.
`protected void cleanup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context)
throws IOException,InterruptedException`

Refer this [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html).